# Merging from xlsx file to InDesign, from two sheets

Tags: merge, xlsx, adobe-indesign

I have looked at google, on how to merge data from a XLSX file into InDesign.
I can see that it's easy from one sheet.. But what if I have a dropdown list on my Sheet 1 (Main) and depending on what I select, then I want it to grab the Title from the (Main) sheet, and then get the sub_info from my Sheet 2 (SubInfo) for that title.

Is it possible to merge from two sheets (Excel/XLSX file) into a InDesign file ?
If yes, how ?

My test XLSX file is like this [InDesign-Merging XLSX file](https://easyupload.io/w4jrwg)

Answer (score 0):

InDesign's default data merge option accepts txt and csv documents as database.
Your document is no longer available but as far as I understand, I suggest you try to do this with excel before exporting your csv or txt document.
With the `VLOOKUP` function of Excel you can pull the data from the 2nd sheet to the 1st sheet.